# Wordpress Jetpack Json API not working

Tags: json, wordpress, api, jetpack

i'm trying to use Json API from Jetpack, but when i make the call i only get this:

```
{"error":"unknown_blog","message":"Unknown blog"}
```

I'm trying this: https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/clasari.com/wp/posts/

The blog is hosted at *wp* folder (inside clasari.com) solo the blog url is clasari.com/wp, i guess that can be a problem.

I've also tried

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/clasari.com::wp/posts/

but it has the same result.

Any idea of what can be this problem? Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am struggling with the same problem myself.

Comment: Nope, i gave up and tried another way

Comment: I had to do the same. I switched from example.com/wp to wp.example.com and reconnected Jetpack.

Comment: @jorn if you're still looking for the answer, you can now find it below

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), like this:

```
$url = 'clasari.com/wp';
$url = url_encode( $url );

$request =
  'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/' .
  $url .
  '/posts/';
```